# upload file to a sharepoint online with Axios and FormData

Tags: javascript, fs, form-data

I'm trying to upload files with axios to a SPO server via API.

Problem surely is that I can't open the files to append to data object and send them with Axios.

Here is my code:

```
var uploadFile = async function(token, nombre, url){
    var headerToken = { ... };
    var FormData = require('form-data');
    var formData = new FormData();
    var fs = require('fs');
    var archive = my_url + my_name;
    formData.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(archive));
    var data = {
        data: { formData }
    };

    try {
        var response = await axios.post("API_ENDPOINT", data, headerToken);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

I guess problem is this:
**formData.append('my_file', fs.createReadStream(archive));**

At this moment I'm uploading empty files with right name to SPO server.

Comment: Why are you using createReadStream? I m quite sure you don't require readStream for that, you should be using writeStream unless you have some specific methodology which you are following from the documentation.

Comment: Because I thought in "readng" the file... but I was obviously wrong. To be honest, I am a bit lost ¬¬'

Comment: So do u read a file from a url and upload?

Comment: I have to take a file from a local url and upload it. I assumed that the file must be read or opened in some way in the first place.

Comment: Can you be more specific pls? Local URL means the file exists in ur project or you are talking about the temporary blob?

Comment: "local url" means that there are files in the same server (stored locally) where node app is running. When a request is received (from another app, with a file name and path as parameters), my node app must "take" this file and added as an object to my SPO request.

My problem is that I don't know how take the file from the local server :/

I am so sorry for my bad explanations :P

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible, why don't u upload a file and send it to the server, like using an upload button, and upload a file to the SPO server. If yes, I can help u with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222585/discussion-between-max-and-urvashi).